# EC2 Instance Search in API

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

In the AWS EC2 console on the web, there is a search box that allows you to search for instances by keyword. It appears that this searches many fields (such as hostname, tags, instance state, etc.) for the provided keyword.

Here is an example of searching for the keyword "running". The UI shows a filter named "search" with the search value "running". It appears that this returns instances in the "running" state but also instances named "running", with a tag value of "running", a hostname of "running", etc.

[image: Example search for running]

Is this functionality available through the API? The describe-instances API call has filters, but it appears as though there is no documented filter that matches this behaviour (which searches all fields instead of just the specified ones). I've tried a filter named "search" but that does not work.

Comment: what do you mean by "searches all fields"? I mean you can provide multiple filters. wouldn't that work for you? a sample would be nice to understand the question correctly.

Comment: I've updated the question with more detail, hope this answers your question. I could just add a lot of filters, but I would need to add one for every possible filter key. Also, as I understand it, multiple filters are ANDed together but the behaviour of the search filter is an OR - it will return an instance if any of the filters match

Comment: ah gotcha. thanks for the clarification. they might be cheating a little bit with the management console as they have direct access to everything :-)

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "through the API"? Were you intending to use an SDK or the AWS Command-Line Interface?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein: Don't both SDK and CLI use the same API under the hood? I mean technically you don't even need them to make the API calls but they make life a lot easier. Maybe I'm missing something...

Comment: @Volkan: Yes, but I was trying to clarify whether you wanted the CLI to do the searching for you (with no coding), or if you would be willing to implement it in code using the SDK.

Answer (score 1):

There is no API equivalent that search all fields (eg state, name, tag). However, you could emulate this by retrieving details of ALL instances via the API and then having your app filter the results.

Answer (score 0):

One way I think it can be done is using `aws ec2 describe-instances` (use corresponding API in your preferred language sdk) and do a regex to filter out the results.